# AsyncTask: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views. ( android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException:)

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I am implementing an AsyncTask in my project. The onPrexecute displays the dialog but along the line the app crashes with the error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

This is my AsycTask task code

```
private class CheckTypesTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
             ProgressDialog asyncDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
             String typeStatus;


             @Override
             protected void onPreExecute() {
                 //set message of the dialog
                 asyncDialog.setMessage("Please wait");
                 //show dialog
                 asyncDialog.show();
                 super.onPreExecute();
             }

             @Override
             protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

                 onPhotoTaken(); 

                return null;
             }

             @Override
             protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

                 //hide the dialog
                 asyncDialog.dismiss();
                 asyncDialog = null;
                 super.onPostExecute(result);
             }

     }
```

After research I modified my code to this

```
@Override
             protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            onPhotoTaken();     
                        }
                    });
                return null;
             }
```

EDITTED:
This is the onPhoto taken method

```
public void onPhotoTaken() {

        _taken = true;

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 4;

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_path, options);

        try {
            //ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading", "Please wait...", true);
            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(_path);
            int exifOrientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                    ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                    ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

            Log.v(TAG, "Orient: " + exifOrientation);

            int rotate = 0;

            switch (exifOrientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                rotate = 90;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                rotate = 180;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                rotate = 270;
                break;
            }

            Log.v(TAG, "Rotation: " + rotate);

            if (rotate != 0) {

                // Getting width & height of the given image.
                int w = bitmap.getWidth();
                int h = bitmap.getHeight();

                // Setting pre rotate
                Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
                mtx.preRotate(rotate);

                // Rotating Bitmap
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, false);


            }

            // Convert to ARGB_8888, required by tess
            bitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
            //dialog.dismiss();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't correct orientation: " + e.toString());
        }
        _image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

It works well at this point, but my code display a blank screen.
Thanks in anticipation

Comment: It depend on what doing inside `onPhotoTaken ` method. show code from `onPhotoTaken ` method

Comment: all interaction with UI should called from "onPostExecute", "onPreExecute" or "onProgressUpdate" methods. This methods runs in UI thread. Please show your "onPhotoTaken" method

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Check my edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create the Bitmap in doInBackground.

```
@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    return onPhotoTaken(); 
}
```

...

```
public Bitmap onPhotoTaken() {
    ....
    return bitmap;
}
```

and do the UI tasks in onPostExecute:

```
@Override 
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result){
    ...
    _image.setImageBitmap(result);
}
```

Change `AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>` to `AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>` also

Comment: @Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    return onPhotoTaken(); 
}

Comment: The return type is incompatible with AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>.doInBackground(Void[])

Comment: change AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> to AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>

Comment: Yeah. I have done that, now I am having a leaked window exception

Comment: Please where is this bitmap parameter declared... _image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

Comment: Sry didn't change the name. check my edited answer.  leaked window exceptions are usually caused by a dialog dismiss call, when the activity is already closing/closed.

Comment: So how can I fix this leaked window issue. This is the only issue I am having for now

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850573/activity-has-leaked-window-that-was-originally-added) out. Also check the log for other exceptions. (Before that one)

Comment: Have seen the thread before and my window and dialog is dismissed based on that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95938/discussion-between-oberflansch-and-jng).

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a Handler creating it using `new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());`

Use it to run a task, which will be a call to your method.

Answer (score 1):

You must use `_image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);` on `onPostExecute` method.

[onPostExecute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result)) runs on the UI thread.

As a rule of thumb **never** modify `View`s outside of the `main(UI)` thread.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (and make your onPhotoTaken return a Bitmap instead of setting it):

```
private class CheckTypesTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>{
         ProgressDialog asyncDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
         String typeStatus;


         @Override
         protected void onPreExecute() {
             //set message of the dialog
             asyncDialog.setMessage("Please wait");
             //show dialog
             asyncDialog.show();
             super.onPreExecute();
         }

         @Override
         protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            return onPhotoTaken();
         }

         @Override
         protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

             //hide the dialog
             asyncDialog.dismiss();
             asyncDialog = null;

             if (result != null) {
                  _image.setImageBitmap(result);
             }

             super.onPostExecute(result);
         }

 }
```

So your doInBackground function returns the bitmap instead of applying it to the image. onPostExecute runs in the UI Thread and you can manipulate UI elements like a Imageview without any problems.

Comment: Pretty much like my answer. Note that he has to change `onPhotoTaken` also to return the Bitmap.

Comment: Please where is this bitmap parameter declared... _image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

Comment: @JnG I edited my answer. you have to use the result instead of bitmap.